# Stored Procedure Com Select SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, servidor, procedure

Boa noite, estou tentando criar uma stored procedure que vai buscar um dos dados em um select, o motivo é porque tenho uma tabela de itens, e preciso inserir todos os códigos dos itens em outra tabela.

A ideia é +- essa:
Na tabela item, somente o campo "ItemCodigo" interessa, porem possui varios campos, e tem cerca de 170mil linhas, cada uma com um itemcodigo diferente.

NA tabela ItensUsuario possui a vinculação do usuario com o item e algumas outras informações.

Preciso criar uma stored procedure que vai inserir todos os itens do itemcodigo no itens usuário.

Tentei algumas formas, porém deu erro na conversão de varchar para int (acredito que seja devido ao select que fiz)

```
create procedure inserirtodositens
@idusuario int,
@idproduto int
as 
begin
insert into xx.dbo.itensusuario
values (@idusuario, @idproduto, 0, getdate(),0,-1)
end 

execute inserirtodositens 594, 'select itemcodigo from xx.dbo.itens'
```

O erro que retorna é "Error converting data type varchar to int."

```
Caso eu mude o "@idproduto int" para 
"idproduto varchar(8000) = NULL"
```

O erro que retorna é "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select itemcodigo from xx.dbo.itens' to data type int."

Answer (score 0):

Bruno,

O problema se dá devido ao fato de voce está passando uma string (varchar) para um parametro que espera um numero (int)

A sua procedure "inserirtodositens" tem dois paramatros : @idusuario int, e @idproduto int

A chamada da procedure voce ta passando 594 para ID do usuario e um comando "select itemcodigo from xx.dbo.itens" que realmente vai falhar pois @idproduto espera um valor numerico.

Para alcançar o seu objetivo, tenta o seguinte :

`create procedure inserirtodositens
@idusuario int
as 
begin
insert into xx.dbo.itensusuario
select @idusuario, itemcodigo, 0, getdate(),0,-1 from xx.dbo.itens
where 
   idusuario = @idusuario
end`

execute inserirtodositens 594

To considerando que na tabela tenha o campo idusuario.

Comment: Na tabela itens só tem informação do item, não vincula o usuário, a tabela itensusuario é onde vincula o usuário com o item, eu quero em alguns usuários específicos colocar todos os itens que existem, mas pelo o que entendi o select eu devo fazer dentro da procedure, porém o select sempre retorna um varchar, não tem como converter?

Comment: Nesse caso remova o trecho do "where    idusuario = @idusuario" e no "itemcodigo", caso venha varchar e deseja converter para int. Utilize o Convert(varchar, itemcodigo)